# How to use docker hub registery with IKS deployed on VPC Gen2 infra?

Tags: ibm-cloud

I created a k8s cluster on **IBM VPC Gen2** Infrastructure. When I deployed my application then it can't pull an image from docker hub. I'm getting below error. Port `443` is enabled under `VPC Infrastucture/All Security groups/Rules`. I can't find any documents which can help with this. All the docs are talking about setting up IBM registry and then push the docker image to this registry.

**Error**

```
Failed to pull image "metacontrollerio/metacontroller:v1.4.0": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "docker.io/metacontrollerio/metacontroller:v1.4.0": failed to resolve reference "docker.io/metacontrollerio/metacontroller:v1.4.0": failed to do request: Head "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/metacontrollerio/metacontroller/manifests/v1.4.0": dial tcp 107.23.X.X:443: i/o timeout
```

**Mode of deployment**

***deployed using CLI with the help of kustomize***

**Metacontroller yaml file**

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: metacontroller
  name: metacontroller
  namespace: metacontroller
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: metacontroller
  serviceName: ""
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: metacontroller
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: metacontroller
      containers:
      - name: metacontroller
        image: metacontrollerio/metacontroller:v1.4.0
        command: ["/usr/bin/metacontroller"]
        args:
        - --logtostderr
        - -v=4
        - --discovery-interval=20s
  volumeClaimTemplates: []
```

Please help.

Comment: Add more details. From where are you executing the pull? Does that machine have access to Dockerhub, does a ping work? BTW: For Kubernetes there are docs on enabling Dockerhub: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/containers?topic=containers-registry

Comment: `pull` requests is being executed from the worker nodes. I can't see any public-ip attached to the worker nodes. Is there any way to ssh into the worker nodes? 

Edit: sure I'll look into the docs.

Comment: The worker node does not need a public IP. You are opening the connection from there. But is the outbound traffic enabled? What rules are enabled?

Comment: yes outbound traffic is enabled for `Port:ALL, Destination Type: Any, Destination: 0.0.0.0/0`

Comment: I have to enable traffic here ```VPC Infrastructure/All security groups for VPC/security_group_name```. Right?

Comment: for k8s security group name `kube-cluster_id`. The outboud traffic is enabled for ip `172.10.0.0/18` only.

Comment: even enabling outbound traffic for all in `kube-cluster_id` security group didn't fix the issue.

Comment: There are many ways of creating the K8s cluster in a VPC (CLI, Terraform, UI, ...). Then, you specify for your K8s deployment how to pull / deploy a container image. Add more details to your question and tag it with more keywords

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230019/discussion-between-alpha-and-data-henrik).

Comment: figured out: go to `https://cloud.ibm.com/vpc-ext/network/subnet` and enable `Public Gateway` to allow worker nodes to access public internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to `https://cloud.ibm.com/vpc-ext/network/subnet`.
2. Select your VPC.
3. Enable `Public gateway(bottom corner)` to allow worker nodes to access public internet.